# OS X Core Data - Passing a Managed Object Context to a View Controller

Tags: macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I am developing a Mac Application in Xcode 7.3.1. and I am trying to pass a Model Object Context from my AppDelegate to an ArrayController.

I have a class named DataController which creates my Core Data stack. DataController.managedObjectContext holds the Managed Object Context.

My AppDelegate class is as follows:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  var dataController: DataController!

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    // Create an instance of the DataController class.
    dataController = DataController()

    // Create a reference to the first ViewController embedded in the WindowController.
    guard let splitViewController = NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].contentViewController as? ManagedObjectContextSettable
        else { fatalError("Wrong view controller type")}

    // Set the managedObjectContext property.
    splitViewController.managedObjectContext = dataController.managedObjectContext
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
  }

}
```

In my storyboard I have embedded a SplitViewController in my WindowController. The SplitViewController has its own custom View Controller class named SplitViewController. Here is the code in the SplitViewController:

```
class SplitViewController: NSSplitViewController, ManagedObjectContextSettable {

  var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.


    // Create a reference to the first ViewController embedded in the WindowController.
    let childControllers = self.childViewControllers

    print("childControllers.count = \(childControllers.count)")

    for childController in childControllers{

        if childController.isKindOfClass(TableViewController){

            print("Found TableViewController")

            guard let tableViewController = childController as? ManagedObjectContextSettable
                else { fatalError("Wrong view controller type")}

            tableViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Within one of the Split View Items is my TableView which has its own View Controller named TableViewController. Here is the code for TableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: NSViewController, ManagedObjectContextSettable, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

  var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    //print(managedObjectContext.description)
  }

}
```

In the storyboard I dragged an ArrayController and in the Bindings tab of the Inspector I have set Bind To and selected TableViewController and set the Model Key Path to 'self.managedObjectContext'. Ultimately it's not receiving the Managed Object Context.

I cannot establish if I should override the prepareForSegue function for an embedded ViewController, every example I read is for IOS.

Where am I going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDidFinishLaunching` can be executed after `viewDidLoad`. Set `managedObjectContext` of the childControllers when `managedObjectContext` of the splitViewController is set.

Bindings use KVO. Change `var managedObjectContext` to `dynamic var managedObjectContext` to make the property KVO compliant.

Comment: I noticed that AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLoading was executed after all of the ViewController's viewDidLoad methods. Are you suggesting I set the managedObjectContext variable of the SplitViewController's child view controller (TableViewController) in the AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLoading method?

Comment: I'm suggesting `viewDidLoad` of `SplitViewController` can be executed before `viewDidLoad` of `TableViewController`. Implement the setter of `managedObjectContext` and propagate to the childControllers.

Comment: Another possible solution is binding `managedObjectContext` of the arraycontrollers programatically to `dataController.managedObjectContext`. (I think the developers of storyboards and viewcontrollers never heard about bindings)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array controller with Cocoa bindings you have to override the `init(coder:)` method and initialize the managed context there to perform the implicit initial fetch. `viewDidLoad` is too late.

The segue workflow is the same as in iOS. It's even more convenient because there is a property `presentingViewController` to get the reference to the parent view controller.

The Core Data Manager `DataController` is supposed to be a singleton to ensure that the managed object context instance is always the same.

Comment: Very helpful. So do I override the init in the AppDelegate to pass the MOC to the SplitViewController and then override the prepareForSegue in the SplitViewController to pass the MOC to the TableViewController?

Comment: Not in AppDelegate, only in the controllers which use array controller and bindings. If you use a singleton, initialize the stack in AppDelegate and then get the context from the singleton.

Comment: I create an instance of my DataController class directly within the controller where the ArrayController is. So why do Apple suggest that I pass the MOC from AppDelegate to the Window's child view controllers, and from them down to their children?

Comment: Apple does not recommend to use different instances of a custom Core Data Controller class. You can do the recommended way to keep the Core Data code in AppDelegate and pass the managed context respectively, but then you have to perform an additional "manual" fetch because the bindings are established much earlier before `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: `fetch:` is deferred until the next iteration of the runloop. Setting the managedObjectContext in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is early enough.

Comment: For an OS X application, in what circumstances is prepareForSegue called? My WindowController contains my SplitViewController with an embed segue. The top panel of my SplitViewController contains my TableViewController also with an embed segue. Should I use 'prepareForSegue' to pass the MOC down to the modelObjectContext property within my TableViewController class?

If I override prepareForSegue within my SplitViewController and my TableViewController classes and simply include a print within these methods I get no results making me think the methods are not called.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be good practice, but it appears to work.

I made my DataController class a singleton class to ensure there was only one Managed Object Context. In my TableViewController I created a managedObjectContext property as follows:

```
    lazy var managedObjectContext = DataController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
```

In my array controller I bind the managed object context parameter to the TableViewController and set the Model Key Path to self.managedObjectContext.

Can this be improved upon?